# Why doesn't '2>' mean indent 2 levels on vim?

Tags: vim

I've been using vim for sometime now but only recently started learning how to really use it.
I have some questions about what seems like puzzling behavior.

Why `2>` doesn't mean indent 2 levels instead of indent 2 lines? `>2j` already serves the same purpose and indenting 2 levels seems like the more intuitive behavior.

Another similar question is why does 'G' means jump to last line but '10G' mean jump to 10th line from the **top** of the buffer instead of from the bottom of the buffer.

How can these issues be fixed properly?

***Should I?*** Could changing the behavior break plugins or anything?

---

Note: I'd like to mention that I know *how* to get the functionality I want, ie.
`:>>` for multi-level indent and `:$-10` for jump to n'th line for bottom.

Comment: If you want 2> to indent twice just press v to drop into visual mode and it inserts two tabs or spaces if you have it set to use spaces

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**`2>>`**

The behavior you describe is due to how `{count}` works with *line-wise commands*: it doesn't perform the command `{count}` times but considers `{count}` as the number of lines on which to act.

You can get a glimpse at how Vim does its thing by doing `2:`, this is what you should get in the command-line:

```
:.,.+1
```

Doing `2>>` is thus the equivalent of:

```
:.,.+1>
```

"Indent this line and the one below by one level".

In normal mode, just hit `>>` to indent the current line by one level and repeat until you are at the right level.

If you want `2>` to indent by two levels, you must first visually select the line: `V2>` or `v2>`.

If you want to "fix" the indentation of the current line so that it matches the indentation of the surrounding lines (the most common scenario for such a task), hit `==`.

**`10G`**

`G` expects a `{count}` to jump to the corresponding line. Without a `{count}` it defaults to jumping to the last line: you can see it as a convenient shortcut for `{lines in buffer}G`.

So you are inverting things a little: `G` is not "jump to last line", it's "jump to line `{count}` but without a `{count}` so let's go the last one".

*-- Startedit --*

Let's reverse-engineer `G` for fun:

1. `G` is first conceived as the normal mode equivalent of `:number<CR>`.
2. It is decided that, instead of doing `G23`, the `{count}` mechanism is used so we have `23G`. `G` is not an operator: it doesn't wait for a target.
3. But what do we do with `G`, without a `{count}`?
4. Generally, a buffer has two "special" lines: the first and the last. Maybe we can decide what the default destination for `G` is? Why not? We hate wasted keys!
5. `G` is not much shorter than `1G` but it's shorter so that could be a good idea to make `G` jump to the first line.
6. But what about the last line? `12G` is OK when we *know* there are 12 lines in the buffer but what about 1257 lines? What about an unknown number of lines? Is it that efficient to look up the number and type `2431G`? No, at that point, we might as well do `:$<CR>`. Well, why don't we use `G`, here? It is vastly shorter and quicker than any other way to reach the last line.

(this is pure speculation, of course, I have no idea what Bill Joy had in mind when he designed `G`.)

*-- Endedit --*

**Fixing Vim**

Generally, Vim doesn't need to be "fixed". Instead, you must learn how it works and how to leverage its power. Most of it makes a lot of sense: when you'll "get it" the reward will be huge.

Also, the behavior of *everything* is explained in `:help`: learning how to use it is the number one skill you must grow if you are serious about using Vim.